# Regex rewriting with map

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I have a `url.map` containing a rewrite rule

```
~^/A/shopby/(?<brand>[a-zA-Z]+) ~^/category/by-brand/$brand;
```

so that `/A/shopby/a_brand` will be redirect to `/category/by-brand/a_brand`

And also a `config file`

```
map $request_uri $new_uri {
  include /etc/nginx/urls.map;
}

server {
  rewrite_log on;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

  if ($new_uri) {
     # return 200 $new_uri; for debugging
     rewrite $request_uri $new_uri permanent;
  }

 location / {
   root /a_root;
   index  index.html;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }
}
```

And I keep getting this 

`*60 "$request_uri" does not match "/A/shopby/a_brand"`

and also my debugging only returned me `~^/category/by-brand/$brand` which showed regex didn't replace the captured string

What did I miss in the process? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your `rewrite` statement is incorrect, as the first parameter should be a regular expression and not a variable.

But you do not need to use `rewrite` when you are changing the entire URI. A permanent rewrite is equivalent to a `return 301`.

For example:

```
if ($new_uri) {
    return 301 $new_uri;
}
```

If you need to pass the original arguments (which `rewrite` would do by default), use:

```
if ($new_uri) {
    return 301 $new_uri$is_args$args;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) for details.